# How to create a common assets folder for multiple locale in angular

Tags: angular, localization, angular-localize

I am localizing my angular app for 2 languages by following the [official guide](https://angular.io/guide/i18n). During production build, I get one folder for each `locale` and each folder has its own `assets` folder. This has a couple of issues

1. My images don't get served at `dev` and `prod` environments simultaneously unless I take out the assets folder after deploying the app.
2. The manual process requires extras step for automated deployment
3. Having two assets folder is a waste of disc space

Is there a way I can configure `angular.json` so that I will have a common `assets` folder outside of the locale folders as shown in the figure below?

[image]